# How to get Google Authenticator passcode into our app without manual entering

Tags: android, two-factor-authentication

How  to get Google Authenticator pass code into our android app without swap the app and manual entering when  enable Two-Factor Authentication to my developed app

Comment: I doubt that this is possible. There is no programmatic way for Google Authenticator to validate that your app has any right to that data.

Comment: So, is no other way ? instead of enter the pass code manually

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

I know it's not Google Authenticator, but I do have a product that you can use to get a frictionless 2 factor authentication process without making your user copy the digits across to your application.

Twilio two factor authentication offers what we call [OneTouch](https://www.twilio.com/two-factor-authentication/features#onetouch). It sends a push notification to the [Authy](http://authy.com/) app which the user can then approve or deny within the application and carry on using your app.

As far as I know, you cannot achieve this with Google Authenticator.